# Content Control in Word IPad

Tags: ipad, office-js

I have a question using the Content Controls in Word IPad. I am creating the specific Content Control on Word Desktop using OfficeJS and then I want to access this Content Control on Word IPad. But apparently it's not possible, because there is no way to select Content Control in Word IPad.

Based on the Office Development documentation Content Controls are supported in Word for IPad.

[Content Control in Microsoft Word](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol?product=word)

Here is the screenshot of selected Content Control in Microsoft Word desktop:

[image]

So, how to select the Content Control in the Word IPad?

Comment: I just tested opening a Word document with content control in Word on the iPad. You definitely put the focus in the control and enter information. However, the content control does not appear the same way in Word on the iPad as in Word for Windows. You won't see the tag/title or the entry box - all you'll see is the default text, such as "Click here to enter text". Once an entry has been made, there's no way to distinguish the content control from other text. Have you tried that? If yes, are you sure the content control is *enabled* and not locked?

Comment: Hi, @CindyMeister. Thanks for your response. That's exactly the problem because I am trying to access this Content Control programmatically and I need the whole Content Control selected. Since I cannot select the whole Content Control (only the content inside), my function doesn't work on IPad, which is strange because Content Control support is advertised on Microsoft site.

Comment: referring to the info in the link to the dev site: Are you using a RichText content control (other types aren't supported)? What is your code trying to do with the content control, please post code (as per SO rules) so that people can repro what you're seeing.